# Observable issue with async pipe

Tags: angularjs, angular, observable, observablelist, reactivex

im using a [library](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) that help me to sort a list with drag-and-drop.

and the list that im giving it is an Observable of the list type, and then im using async to read it in the html, its very simple and looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {

  myList: Observable<MyListType[]>;

  showingList = false;

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
  };


  public showListData(): void {
    this.showingList = true;
    this.myList = this._myService.getListData();
  }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
  <button md-button
          (click)="showListData()"
          title="">Show List
  </button>

</div>


<md-content>

  <div *ngIf="showingList">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="myList | async">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of myList | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> Name: {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>Current List {{myList | async | json}}</div>
  </div>

</md-content>
```

now this does not work, BUT, if I do this in my component instead of   `myList: Observable<MyListType[]>;`

I do:

```
  myList  = this._myService.getListData();
```

and then in the html pass myList it works great...

I dont get it!! drive me crazy :/

please help

`getListData()` like like this:

```
public getListData(): Observable<MyListType[]> {
    return this._someApiService.getCurrentListData().map(res => res.info);
  }
```

Comment: how does getListData() look like?

Comment: @micronyks added to the question in the end buddy

Comment: try this---> *ngFor="let item of myList | async; let i = index";

Comment: @micronyks tried it before it dosent work :/ this make my view not visible